# app crashes on JSON jparser make http request

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, crash

hi i use this tutorial for connecting to the mySQL db on the web or local.
[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
although the all server side php files are correct and works on the browser, but in Android side the app crashes on this line:

```
 JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
```

with this message: unfortunately app has stopped!

i find out on tutorial page comments that i should change some setting on apache server.
here is my code:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/android/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        StrictMode.enableDefaults();

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Log.i("LOG", "load data preexecute");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            Log.i("LOG", "load data inback ");
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            Log.i("LOG", "load data inback json 1 ");

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);


            Log.i("LOG", "load data inback json 2 "+json.toString());

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse


            try {

                Log.i("LOG", "load data inback json json 3");
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                        Log.i("LOG", "load data inback json json 4");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("LOG", "load data inback json json 5");
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                Log.i("All Products: ","success:"+ success+"");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("LOG", "load data inback json on catch");
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

this is log cat:

```
01-11 13:49:19.163: E/Trace(2045): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-11 13:49:19.642: D/gralloc_goldfish(2045): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-11 13:49:26.103: I/LOG(2045): load data preexecute
01-11 13:49:26.583: D/dalvikvm(2045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 3% free 8222K/8391K, paused 155ms, total 170ms
01-11 13:49:26.793: I/LOG(2045): load data inback 
01-11 13:49:26.793: I/LOG(2045): load data inback json 1 
01-11 13:49:27.022: I/Choreographer(2045): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-11 13:49:27.923: W/System.err(2045): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-11 13:49:27.933: W/System.err(2045):     at com.mjs.test.phptest92.core.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:61)
01-11 13:49:27.943: W/System.err(2045):     at com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:138)
01-11 13:49:27.943: W/System.err(2045):     at com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
01-11 13:49:27.943: W/System.err(2045):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-11 13:49:27.943: W/System.err(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-11 13:49:27.943: W/System.err(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-11 13:49:27.943: W/System.err(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-11 13:49:27.953: W/System.err(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-11 13:49:27.953: W/System.err(2045):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-11 13:49:27.953: W/System.err(2045): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
01-11 13:49:28.023: W/System.err(2045):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-11 13:49:28.023: W/System.err(2045):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-11 13:49:28.033: W/System.err(2045):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-11 13:49:28.033: W/System.err(2045):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-11 13:49:28.033: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-11 13:49:28.033: W/System.err(2045):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-11 13:49:28.033: W/System.err(2045):     ... 15 more
01-11 13:49:28.033: W/System.err(2045): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
01-11 13:49:28.043: W/System.err(2045):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-11 13:49:28.053: W/System.err(2045):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-11 13:49:28.053: W/System.err(2045):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-11 13:49:28.053: W/System.err(2045):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-11 13:49:28.053: W/System.err(2045):     ... 20 more
01-11 13:49:28.053: E/Buffer Error(2045): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 13:49:28.093: E/JSON Parser(2045): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
01-11 13:49:28.123: W/dalvikvm(2045): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:141)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-11 13:49:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     ... 4 more
01-11 13:49:28.843: I/Choreographer(2045): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-11 13:49:29.163: I/Choreographer(2045): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045): Activity com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41223f00 that was originally added here
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41223f00 that was originally added here
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:124)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at com.mjs.test.phptest92.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:62)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-11 13:49:29.713: E/WindowManager(2045):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 13:49:29.713: I/Choreographer(2045): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

how i can solve this problem?

Comment: show your logcat lag.

Comment: have u added internet permission in manifest?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya: yes i add that promission

Comment: have u checked the path of get_all_products.php? is it correct?

Comment: failed to connect your address unknown host exception. your error already had ans and solution to.

Comment: @AnilBhatiya: yes the address is right and work on browser.

Comment: @Kenji whats on line 141?

Comment: @mcd : so what is the solution?

Comment: @kenji 
Handle Exception SocketException.ClientProtocolException,ConnectTimeoutException

Comment: @Kenji: check my answer to get idea about difference between calling service from localhost and actual device..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to a `localhost` from your device than use the `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` instead of the `http://127.0.0.1/` or `http://localhost/`.

Because your Android emulator is running on a `Virtual Machine(QEMU)` and you can not connect to a server directly running on your PC.

And If you running your app from Physical android device then please use your network ip from your PC.
for example  `http://198.10.12.21:80/`....

Comment: If your service in local host and you test service from real device then please make sure your pc and device both in same network and use ip address of this network...i hope you got the point....

Comment: thanks. it's so helpful. but after i reinstall the apache because of inner problem the app wont work and my load dialog show for ever. what is this problem. it seems that IP is ok so app wont crash.

Comment: check port no because after reinstall the apache it may change some times...please upvote answer if its work for you ...