# how to get data from sql server using web service in android

Tags: android, sql

how do i get data from sql server using web service in android and show that data in listview in next page on click the button. what is the method to connect android application to webservices, where i insert code to conncet to the webservices

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ab" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_persons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:text="@string/text_persons"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_persons"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edit_persons"
    android:text="@string/text_amount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_persons"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_persons"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_persons"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_persons"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_amount"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_amount"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_persons"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_amount"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_findfood"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_amount"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="@string/button_findfood" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:text="@string/button_map" />
```

here is my mainactivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText editPersons, editAmount;
String youramount, yourpersons;
//KSOAP
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Products";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Products";
        final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:22781/WebService.asmx?op=Products";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Go to Next Page
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_findfood);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    propertyInfo.name="amount";
    propertyInfo.name="persons";

    editPersons=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_persons);
    editAmount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_amount);
    yourpersons=editPersons.getText().toString();
    youramount=editAmount.getText().toString();
    request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

        try  { 
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
            Object response = envelope.getResponse();                    
        }catch (Exception exception)   {

   }            
        }
    });

}
```

here is my web service

```
    [WebMethod]
public DataSet Products(decimal amount, decimal persons)
{

    decimal price = amount / persons;
    DataSet result = null;
    const string SQL_COMMAND_TEXT = "SELECT Menu,Price FROM ASD WHERE Price <= @price";
    using (SqlConnection connection = WebSerConnection.GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL_COMMAND_TEXT, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Persons", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@persons"].Value = persons;
            command.Parameters["@price"].Value = price;
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                result = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(result);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Refere this [Network error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062060/app-crashes-on-json-jparser-make-http-request/21062282#21062282)

Comment: Replace this `final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:22781` your network's ip address like `"http://198.1.1.20:22781"`

Answer (score 0):

1. First and for most thing for you is: You can't make a web API call or can't perform any long running task on main UI directly. FYI, you are making a web call in `onCreate()` method directly without implementing threading mechanism.

   You can implement `AsyncTask` to resolve this issue.
2. Second, you can't use `http://localhost` because it refers to the device on which you are trying to test/run your application. Check for more about this issue: [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CallSoap 
{

public String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CreateEvent";

public String OPERATION_NAME = "CreateEvent"; 

public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

public String erorr="";

public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://xxxx/Service1.asmx";

SoapObject request;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;

//AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport;
HttpTransportSE androidHttp;

public CallSoap() 
{ 
}


protected void SetEnvelope() {

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        // Creating SOAP envelope           
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //You can comment that line if your web service is not .NET one.
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttp = new HttpTransportSE("xxxx/Service1.asmx");

        androidHttp.debug = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Soap Exception---->>>" + e.toString());    
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SimpldurationFormat")
public int Send(decimal amount, decimal persons)
{
    int id=0;
    try{
            //request
            request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

            PropertyInfo pi5=new PropertyInfo();
            pi5.setType(decimal.class);
            pi5.setName("amount");
            pi5.setValue(amount);
            request.addProperty(pi5);

            PropertyInfo pi6=new PropertyInfo();
            pi6=new PropertyInfo();
            pi6.setType(decimal.class);
            pi6.setName("persons");
            pi6.setValue(persons);
            request.addProperty(pi6);

            SetEnvelope();
            //Create envelope
        }
    catch (Exception exception)
        {
        erorr= "error:"+exception.toString();
        }
    try
        {
            androidHttp.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            //Vector<String> result = null;
            //result = (Vector<String>) envelope.getResponse();
            String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            try { 
                id=Integer.parseInt(result); 
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
                erorr=result;
            }
        }
    catch (Exception exception)
        {
        erorr= "error:"+exception.toString();
        }
    }
```