# Execute SQL Stored Procedures for the Native Android App

Tags: android, sql-server, database, android-studio, stored-procedures

I'm developing a native android app and would like to execute stored procedures which are already being used for the web application.

I have used the following links to connect my android app to the SQL Database, which I was able to do successfully.

http://seotoolzz.com/android/android-login-app-with-mssql-server.php

However, to execute the stored procedures, I thought of doing it by having web services in the middle layer (as explained in the below link) and that hasnt worked.

[how to get data from sql server using web service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575914/how-to-get-data-from-sql-server-using-web-service-in-android.)

Kindly let me know how can I execute the stored procedures.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access an MS SQL database through the network using JDBC.  Here is some example code of how to construct a URL to access the database:

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + "/" + database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";";
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("Error:", se.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to execute stored procedure and have already connected to the database successfully then run the following:

USE *dbname*;
GO
EXEC *dbo.spname* *@param1* = *value*;